# Detecting in code when it was packaged by Webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

When packaging our Node.js application, we change some underlying folder structure, so the paths need to be adjusted at run-time, and the app simply needs to know whether or not it was packaged via webpack.

What is the easiest/best approach with Webpack to tell a Node.js app that it was packaged?

Answer (score 1):

This worked well eventually...

In `webpack.config.js`:

```
plugins: [  
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      PACKAGED: true
    })
```

And then in the Node.js code:

```
function isPackaged() {
    return typeof PACKAGED !== 'undefined' && !!PACKAGED;
}
```

During packaging, webpack replaces such code with:

```
function isPackaged() {
    return "boolean" !== 'undefined' && !!true;
}
```

So we get `false` when running unpackaged code, and `true` after it was packaged.